# Resolving Intermittent Lag Time for urlopen and request.get

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urlopen

Using `urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")` or `requests.get(("http://google.com")` results in extended time delay (~1 minute or more) prior to getting response.

Hey everyone,

I am trying to do some web scraping using some code that relies on urllib. Things were going well yesterday, but today I'm getting significant time lags. I've narrowed it down to urllib and reproduced the problem in requests.get. Basically when I run the below code it takes roughly 1 minute to get a response. This was not happening yesterday. The response is good, but I am just not aware of what is happening in the backend to cause the delay. Any suggestions on how to debug, or do you all have an idea of what could be going on?

Thanks in advance.

My OS:Ubuntu 18.04

```py
import urllib
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
print(response)
```

I get the result I am looking for, but the problem I'm running into is it takes >1min of load time...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few solutions:
1. You have a slow connection due to a service provider issue.
2. You have too many taks / cpu overload (not sure how slow your computer is tho)

Try restarting your computer and restarting your wifi. It may be a hardware issue and I there are many possible solutions. I do not believe that it is a problem with your code because storing a variable into an object is not at all a demanding task. I suggest you follow these steps that I have provided and give me an update if it works / didn't work :)